# 10 Tiles positioning with jQuery or CSS

Tags: jquery, css, positioning, tiles

I'm kind of new to CSS and jQuery. I'm trying to position tiles on a website as follows:

[image: boxes]

I've been trying with CSS and the jQuery Masonry, but the closest I've gotten was like this:

[image: now]

Any one have any clues how I can get the tiles positioned like that.

```
<body>

<nav id="container">
    <div class="t1">1</div>
    <div class="t2">2</div>
    <div class="t3">3</div>
    <div class="t4">4</div>
    <div class="t5">5</div>
    <div class="mi">MIDDLE</div>
    <div class="t6">6</div>
    <div class="t7">7</div>
    <div class="t8">8</div>
    <div class="t9">9</div>
    <div class="t10">10</div>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    margin:auto;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:600px;
    margin-top:140px;
}
.t1, .t2 {
padding:8px;
height:120px;
width:300px;
float:left;
background-color:orange;
border:black thin solid;
}
.t3, .t4, .t5 {
padding:8px;
height:120px;
width:240px;
float:left;
background-color:orange;
border:black thin solid;
}

.t6, .t7, .t8 {
padding:8px;
height:120px;
width:30%;
float:left;
background-color:orange;
border:black thin solid;
}

.t9, .t10 {
padding:8px;
height:120px;
width:300px;
float:left;
background-color:orange;
border:black thin solid;
}
.mi {
height:360px;
width:400px;
background-color:blue;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Can you put the code here too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final code, using Bootstrap:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span6">BOX 1</div>
<div class="span6">BOX 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="span2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">BOX 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">BOX 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">BOX 5</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="span8">
    BOX with blue background
</div>
<div class="span2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">BOX 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">BOX 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">BOX 8</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="span6">BOX 9</div>
<div class="span6">BOX 10</div>
</div>


</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#contain {
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:120px;
    margin-left:600px;
}
.span6 {
    background:#06C;
    width:300px;
    height:120px;
    border:black thin solid;
    margin-left:-20px;
}
.span12 {
    background:#9C0;
    width:100px;
    height:120px;
    border:black thin solid;
    margin-left:-20px;
}
.span8 {
    background:#903;
    width:400px;
    height:364px;
    border:black thin solid;
    margin-left:-80px;
    margin-top:0px;

}
```

[image: Final tiles]

Answer (score 0):

I've been using twitter bootstrap - you can define a row or a container, and tell bootstrap how many colums and what ratios of screen space to make them at in a relatively easy manner.

I used bootstrap because Im also very new to CSS and jQuery.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span6">BOX 1</div>
<div class="span6">BOX 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="span2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">BOX 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">BOX 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">BOX 5</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="span8">
    BOX with blue background
</div>
<div class="span2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">BOX 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">BOX 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">BOX 8</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="span6">BOX 9</div>
<div class="span6">BOX 10</div>
</div>
```

Maybe you must change `padding` and `margin` of row elements, to fit it to the grid.

Comment: Should I use that code with twitter bootstrap? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Also read [this](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)

```
<style type="text/css">
div{
    border:thin solid #000
}
#container{
    width:100%;
}
#container div{
    float:left;
    width:49%;/* make this 50 and turn off borders */
height:20%
}
#container div:nth-child(odd){
    clear:both;
}
#container .mi{
  position: absolute;
margin: 0 auto;
top: 50%;
height: 50%;
margin-left: 25%;
margin-top: -14%;

}
</style>      
<nav id="container">

    <div class="t1">1</div>
    <div class="t2">2</div>
    <div class="t3">3</div>
    <div class="t4">4</div>
    <div class="t5">5</div>

    <div class="t6">6</div>
    <div class="t7">7</div>
    <div class="t8">8</div>
    <div class="t9">9</div>
    <div class="t10">10</div>
    <div class="mi">MIDDLE</div>
</div>
```